# keep one or more divs always in center of parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a portfolio like thing, but no images in it.
Actually I want a parent div container 1,2 or 3 divs in it. When three is only one div of about 30% - 33% of width inside, it must look in the center of the parent div
i.e ( ---- div ---- ).

When there are 2 divs inside, those two must look in center of the parent div,
i.e ( -- div div -- )

even when I enter fourth div the parent div keep them all in middle, same margin / padding on left and right.
i.e ( div div div )

if I enter more divs under already present divs, the new one goes exactly the same way under these.

( ---- div ---- )    only one div
( -- div div -- )    two divs
( div  div  div )    three divs

[I need these divs with some background and will put text in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRJ5W.png)

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take a read here to help get answers to your questions -> [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have u tried so far??

Comment: no code no chocolate, in other words, if you don't set up a simple HTML/CSS case that shows your issue, you are likely letting  us waste time for guessing what is your real question ....

Comment: I tried this on images and it works good. But when I come to div, one div is easily settled in the center by using margin: 0 auto;
and by default div comes after another div so my next div comes down

Comment: When I use float: left and margin: 0 auto; it works but float is not what I want. I want it to take CSS by staying in middle of the parent div

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: inline-block` css property. [Read more](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block-layout.html) about this to learn how can you use it to center align elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 8px 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.child-holder {
  line-height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-holder">Child 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-holder">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-holder">Child 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-holder">Child 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-holder">Child 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.parent {text-align:center}
.child {display:inline-block;width:33%}

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.child {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
.parent {
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean but there's a guide to flexbox I use for reference - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/